# DeepLabv3+ Keras Custom Channel Implementation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation, deeplab

I am trying to use the Keras implementation of DeepLabV3+ for a binary segmentation task using a custom number of channels (ex. 4 instead of 3).

What I have modified so far:

- I know that I cannot use the imagenet weights (trained for 3 channels), so I have changed the weights to None (random).
- I have changed the input shape for a 4-channel implementation: keras.Input(shape=(image_size, image_size, 4))
- Since this is a binary segmentation task, I changed the output with a sigmoid activation: model_output = layers.Conv2D(num_classes, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding="same", activation='sigmoid')(x)

Here is the original code if the link is unavailable:

```
def convolution_block(
    block_input,
    num_filters=256,
    kernel_size=3,
    dilation_rate=1,
    padding="same",
    use_bias=False,
):
    x = layers.Conv2D(
        num_filters,
        kernel_size=kernel_size,
        dilation_rate=dilation_rate,
        padding="same",
        use_bias=use_bias,
        kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.HeNormal(),
    )(block_input)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)


def DilatedSpatialPyramidPooling(dspp_input):
    dims = dspp_input.shape
    x = layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(dims[-3], dims[-2]))(dspp_input)
    x = convolution_block(x, kernel_size=1, use_bias=True)
    out_pool = layers.UpSampling2D(
        size=(dims[-3] // x.shape[1], dims[-2] // x.shape[2]), interpolation="bilinear",
    )(x)

    out_1 = convolution_block(dspp_input, kernel_size=1, dilation_rate=1)
    out_6 = convolution_block(dspp_input, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=6)
    out_12 = convolution_block(dspp_input, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=12)
    out_18 = convolution_block(dspp_input, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=18)

    x = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([out_pool, out_1, out_6, out_12, out_18])
    output = convolution_block(x, kernel_size=1)
    return output

def DeeplabV3Plus(image_size, num_classes):
    model_input = keras.Input(shape=(image_size, image_size, 3))
    resnet50 = keras.applications.ResNet50(
        weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_tensor=model_input
    )
    x = resnet50.get_layer("conv4_block6_2_relu").output
    x = DilatedSpatialPyramidPooling(x)

    input_a = layers.UpSampling2D(
        size=(image_size // 4 // x.shape[1], image_size // 4 // x.shape[2]),
        interpolation="bilinear",
    )(x)
    input_b = resnet50.get_layer("conv2_block3_2_relu").output
    input_b = convolution_block(input_b, num_filters=48, kernel_size=1)

    x = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([input_a, input_b])
    x = convolution_block(x)
    x = convolution_block(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D(
        size=(image_size // x.shape[1], image_size // x.shape[2]),
        interpolation="bilinear",
    )(x)
    model_output = layers.Conv2D(num_classes, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding="same")(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=model_output)

model = DeeplabV3Plus(image_size=IMAGE_SIZE, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
```

Here is the code with my changes for 4-channel input and binary output:

```
def DeeplabV3Plus(image_size, num_classes=1):
    model_input = keras.Input(shape=(image_size, image_size, 4))
    resnet50 = keras.applications.ResNet50(
        weights=None, include_top=False, input_tensor=model_input
    )
    x = resnet50.get_layer("conv4_block6_2_relu").output
    x = DilatedSpatialPyramidPooling(x)

    input_a = layers.UpSampling2D(
        size=(image_size // 4 // x.shape[1], image_size // 4 // x.shape[2]),
        interpolation="bilinear",
    )(x)
    input_b = resnet50.get_layer("conv2_block3_2_relu").output
    input_b = convolution_block(input_b, num_filters=48, kernel_size=1)

    x = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([input_a, input_b])
    x = convolution_block(x)
    x = convolution_block(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D(
        size=(image_size // x.shape[1], image_size // x.shape[2]),
        interpolation="bilinear",
    )(x)
    model_output = layers.Conv2D(num_classes, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding="same", activation='sigmoid')(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=model_output)

model = DeeplabV3Plus(image_size=IMAGE_SIZE, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
```

However, I am getting the following errors:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert'
```

and

```
Node: 'assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert'
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  assertion failed: [predictions must be >= 0] [Condition x >= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (model_5/conv2d_59/Sigmoid:0) = ] [[[[nan][nan][nan]]]...] [y (Cast_8/x:0) = ] [0]
     [[{{node assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]]
     [[assert_greater_equal_1/Assert/AssertGuard/pivot_f/_23/_65]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  assertion failed: [predictions must be >= 0] [Condition x >= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (model_5/conv2d_59/Sigmoid:0) = ] [[[[nan][nan][nan]]]...] [y (Cast_8/x:0) = ] [0]
     [[{{node assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]]
```

Note: My images and masks are scaled to 0-1.

Answer (score 0):

The provided code is the correct implementation of a 4-channel version of DeepLabV3+ for binary segmentation in Keras. My error was caused by a poorly formed 4 channel input data.